# RobotFramework, perform different tear down action for each suite

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Teardown  Perform suite teardown

*** Keywords ***
Perform suite teardown
    Log to console          Test suite cleanup
    cleanUp                 ${a}  ${b}  ${c}

*** Test Cases ***
TEST 1
    do some action

TEST 2
    do another action
```

The above code works well and run a suite tear down.I have a scenario where I want to run a different tear down action for each test case, how can I modify the above example to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "after running each suite"? You've only shown a single suite, and the suite teardown only affects this one suite. You seem to be conflating "suite" and "test case".

Comment: that was a mistake in my question, I corrected it later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be using "suite" when it should be using "test case". Your example shows only a single suite, and the suite teardown only affects this one suite.

If you want each *test* to have a separate teardown, you would use `[teardown]` in each test.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TEST 1
    [Teardown]  log  this teardown is unique to TEST 1
    do some action

TEST 2
    [Teardown]  log  this teardown is unique to TEST 2
    do another action
```

For more information see [Test Setup and Teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: thanks for the correction, yes it should b using test case, I will try this solution

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a VERY unique solution. But Lets say you wanted to not have `[Teardown]` everywhere....

```
*** Settings ***

Test Teardown      Teardown ${TEST_NAME}


*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    [Tags]                             example
    Log To Console    ${TEST NAME}

*** Keywords ***
Teardown Test1
    Log To Console     I DID IT
```

It is a bit overboard... but kinda cool